# Is there a difference between わけではない and わけではなく?

Tags: meaning

Or do they both mean the same thing? ("Not necessarily the case")

Answer (score 3):

I use わけではない as one word response. 
And I use わけではなく when I want to continue something after that.

ex.
「それは～というわけなんですか？」
「いや、そういうわけではない」

「それは～というわけなんですか？」
「いや、そういうわけでなく、～というわけなんです」